# Strange PHP output corruption

Tags: php, corruption

I'm having a very strange output corruption on one of my PHP sites. Sometimes, a piece of HTML code is displayed, rather than the tags being interpreted. It looks like some characters are missing, messing up the tags. See the example below: the second line should just be a link to **c1**, but due to some reason part of the target URL is shown.

[alt text http://trappist.elis.ugent.be/~wheirman/atuin/tmp/phpstrangeness.png](http://trappist.elis.ugent.be/~wheirman/atuin/tmp/phpstrangeness.png)

The problem is temporary, a refresh usually solves it. This can happen on different parts of the page (although often in the same location). Only Safari seems affected (but I'm suspecting Firefox just masks the problem due to more tolerant parsing). It happens on both my development server as the live one, they both have slightly different settings (output buffering, chunked transfer), although the probability of it happening seems to vary.

Anyone ever seen something like this??

**EDIT**

When I "View Source" in Safari on this page, I get the following HTML:

```
<tr class="odd">
  <td>73</td>
  <td><a href="companies.php?view=1&amp;companyid=73&amp;return=%2Foffice%2Fcompanies.php">c1</a></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><img src='/images/dot_blue.png'  class="altTooltip" alt="inactive: no account"  /> </td>
```

I can't see anything wrong with this, so either Safari has reloaded the page when I asked it for the source, or I'm not looking hard enough...

Comment: could you post a snip of the faulty html page?

Comment: Could you post the HTML that causes this? Maybe run it through a validator and see what comes up.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get the faulty HTML. When I do "View source" in Safari it seems to reload the page and the error is gone...

Comment: What technology are you using to render that table? Plain HTML?

Comment: Your data doesn't change in between outputs?

Comment: And can you try using IE? IE doesn't reload the page when switching into View Source.

Comment: @Pekka: yes, nothing is changing, not even a timestamp somewhere on the page. I can't seem to reproduce this in IE, nor can I find any corrupted output when either downloading the file hundreds of time using `curl`, or when I store it at the server for an instance that did cause corruption in Safari. We're leaning towards a Safari rendering bug...

Comment: @Mark: yes, plain printing of HTML tags. The page passes validation though.

Comment: Could you please post teh PHP that is generating your html. if the problem is there, you will not be able to see it from your output.

Comment: I would use something like http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/ for debugging, just to make sure the browser doesn't silently modify the HTML it receives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem (using Web Inspector): TinyMCE has been inserting  tags (which it uses to load language files and extension modules), at seemingly random places **inside** my own HTML. The result was that, in the case visible from my screenshot, something like `<a href="foo<script src="tinymce/lang/en.js">bar.php">foobar</a>`.

Since I'm also using jQuery on the same page, my guess is it was ultimately cause by jQuery's modifications to the DOM and TinyMCE's additions happening at the same time which resulted in some sort of race condition (caused by a bug that only appears to exhibit itself in Safari).

I am now using the jQuery build of TinyMCE, and all has been well since...

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's my shot in the dark.

The break occurs in the word "office", after the fi character combination. I would bet that the [fi ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Stylistic_ligatures) is -- somehow -- causing trouble.

How exactly? Since that HTML code doesn't contain the ligature character, this might be a bug in Safari. Especially since it occurs randomly. Could you try to rename that file, and see if the problem goes away?

Having valid HTML might also help in avoiding this problem, because it makes parsing easier.

Comment: That's a very clever thought, but it looks like it's part of a URL. I can hardly imagine there really being a `ﬁ` in there.

Comment: Unless it's a bug, and part of the parser treats it as visible text. Then a fi -> ﬁ replacement might make sense.

Comment: I was also thinking towards a Safari rendering bug. Downloading and comparing the file hundreds of times didn't cause any changes, nor was there anything wrong with the page content when I stored it at the server. Moreover, as you can see in the screenshot, the 3 icons at the right are above each other. After a refresh they are next to each other. In both IE and FF I've never seen them rendered vertically.

Comment: I think the vertical positioning is down to the HTML being broken (unclosed tags) - pay them no heed. I find it hard to believe in a rendering bug here, it feels like the data gets garbled somehow - why only in Safari, I don't know. Thomas's `ﬁ` idea is far-fetched but still makes the most sense. What kind of server environment is this? Are there any reverse proxies or something?

Comment: Also, have you tried this on various client computers? This could as well be a firewall / antivirus program on your end.

Comment: Web Inspector to the rescue: TinyMCE has inserted his `<script>` tags inside my own HTML!

Answer (score 1):

When you select a piece of HTML and view source, what you get is not 100% what is there. For instance, all of you &'s are `&amp;`, which probably means you selected the offending text and viewed the selection's source.

If you are still having the issue, trying viewing the whole source code without selecting anything, and then using ctrl + f to find the spot in the code, and try and give us a larger sample, not just the offending row, but a correct row, and in a larger context.

For instance, when using tables, a mislaid `<td>` can have very weird consequences, this doesn't look like that type of issue, I am just saying that we need context to be able to help.

There's also the issue that some browsers, in order to view source, actually resubmit the page and get a second copy of it. I have a feeling that it is the code that's outputting the text, so look and see if you are using something like

```
<?= $someVar ?>
```

and make sure it's not like this:

```
<a href=<?= isset($x) ?'"'. $someVar.'"': '"'.$someOlderVar.'">'?>> xxx </a>
```

So, no selecty, and bigger sample please. And we'd prolly need something from the code that outputs the errored HTML...

Comment: "For instance, all of you &'s are &amp;, which probably means you selected the offending text and viewed the selection's source. " Why would it mean that? It's normal to escape URLs (including putting &amp;) when placing them in HTML.

Comment: You misunderstand, you don't escape HTML Entities in urls, i.e. the ampersand is a valid symbol for urls, it shouldn't be replace by the html entity version,  your urls will behave oddly when you do that.

Comment: @jolierouge: Except that you do escape it while putting it into an HTML document.  `<a href="companies.php?view=1&companyid=73&return=%2Foffice%2Fcompanies.php">` is invalid because there are no companyid and return HTML entities.

Comment: And if the line was that it would be valid. However, it is not "companies.php?view=1&companyid=73&return=%2Foffice%2Fcompanies.php" but this: "companies.php?view=1&amp;companyid=73&amp;return=%2Foffice%2Fcompanies.php"

I hope at this point you see the significant difference between the 2 strings, one uses the ampersand, and one uses and html_entity